# Gaussian Channel: Capacity and Explanation

Tags: signal, communication, signal-processing, digital-communications, telecommunications

Let's consider a gaussian communication channel, which is represented through this scheme:

[image]

Starting by this assumption it is possible to prove that the channel capacity is equal to [image]

The computation of the last one is written in [these slides](http://acts.ing.uniroma1.it/courses/comtheory/2019-2020/LectureSlides/20191031_ComTh&Eng_lecture6_english-Continuous_Capacity.pdf). Now, in these slides this situation is considered:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now I have the following questions:

1) Why is there the filter h(t)? What does it represent? Is it a physical filter that we put in the channel (and if yes, why?) or is it used to model the fact that a channel is naturally a low pass filter?

2) Why is the signal X sampled?

3) Should X be band limited or not? And why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Why is there the filter h(t)? What does it represent? Is it a physical filter that we put in the channel (and if yes, why?) or is it used to model the fact that a channel is naturally a low pass filter?

Real channels filter the signal passed through them.

Transmission lines are lossy at high frequencies. Optical fibers have dispersion that smears out high frequency signals. To use a free space channel you have to pass your signal through a transmitter and a receiver that have bandwidth restrictions.

The channel response \$h(t)\$ represents whatever filtering effect the channel has.

> 2) Why is the signal X sampled?

To obtain quantifiable information from it.

> 3) Should X be band limited or not? And why?

If it wasn't originally, it is after passing it through the ideal band-pass filter \$h(t)\$.

Comment: So can we say that the last formula of the capacity is a more real expression with respect to the first one?

Comment: @Kinka-Byo, the last one is just re-writing the first one in terms of specific parameters defined for this particular problem.